# List all TypeScripts in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, context-mkiv

A TypeScript (as opposed to a font) contains font definitions for the individual font styles (regular, sans, math, etc. and bold, italic, bolditalic, etc.).

I can list all the fonts with `mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern=*`. But since `\setupbodyfont[my-typescript]` takes a TypeScript and not a font, I would like to know the installed TypeScripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default TypeScripts can be found in the `type-imp-*` files in the directory `tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/` (relative to the ConTeXt installation directory).

If you installed TeX on a Mac with TexLive 2013, you can list them as such:

```
ls /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/type-imp-*
```

and used in `\setupbodyfont[my-typescript]` without the `type-imp-` prefix.

Furthermore there are TypeScripts which ship as third party modules. These can be found in `tex/context/third/typescripts/`.

Comment: For me, they are in `texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/fonts/mkiv/`.